# Rails 4 : Saving value as JSON string object/array in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 1 column called '*message_notification*' inside table '*configuration*'. I want to produce save result as JSON object in this column:

```
message_notification: [
  {
    "alert" : "how are you doing today?"
  },
  {
    "alert" : "where have you been today?"
  }
]
```

for the form, i use

```
<%= simple_form_for(@configuration) do |f| %>
  Alert 1: <%= check_box_tag "configuration[message_notification][][alert]", 'how are you doing today?' %><label>Alert 1</label><br/>
  Alert 2: <%= check_box_tag "configuration[message_notification][][alert]", 'where have you been today?' %><label>Alert 2</label><br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

How to achieve this?

[UPDATED]

above code will resolve as a ruby hash (not as JSON)

**my controller**

```
@configuration.message_notification = {
  alert: params[:message][:alert]
}.to_json
```

result:

```
message_notification: [
  {
    "alert" => "how are you doing today?"
  },
  {
    "alert" => "where have you been today?"
  }
]
```

[UPDATED 2]

In console:

```
=> a = value.message_notification
=> "[{\"alert\"=>\"alert1\"}, {\"alert\"=>\"alert2\"}]"
=> puts a
=> [{"alert"=>"alert1"}, {"alert"=>"alert2"}]
=> nil
```

Comment: You are doing fine, what is the issue?

Comment: @AnujDhanju i've update my question above

Comment: you can `require 'json'` and use `to_json` on the `hash`

Comment: @Sravan yup i did that in my controller.. but still produce `=>`.. see my updated above

Comment: check, `puts { 'alert' => params[:message][:alert] }.to_json`

Comment: @Sravan still have `=>`... updated above

Comment: how did you use `to_json` what is there in `value`?

Comment: @Sravan lets try first in console. i try with `puts a.to_json` resolve to `[{\"alert\"=\u003e\"alert1\"}, {\"alert\"=\u003e\"alert2\"}]`

Comment: try these,`hash =  { 'alert' => 'params[:message][:alert]'}.to_json` then  `puts hash`

Comment: @Sravan still same result as `[{\"alert\"=\u003e\"alert1\"}, {\"alert\"=\u003e\"alert2\"}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129496/discussion-between-sravan-and-amirolahmad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, **`to_json`** to convert the **`ruby hash`** to **`JSON object`**

just `require 'json'` in your `controller`.

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"new", "authenticity_token"=>"txroAHF2+YZOrm48DtBZdVqKzxLYyHFq4+GWQFnM6kNldXgRZJMPv0yfj‌​0/tfZVpuVvh39UVX4Fb66FNkkCZqA==", "message"=>{"name"=>"Dan Murphy Roundabout Test", "company"=>"transtech", "location_id"=>"", "message_notification"=>[{"alert"=>"alert1"}, {"alert"=>"alert2"}], "commit"=>"save", "controller"=>"message", "action"=>"create", "id"=>"1717"}}
```

Since your `params object` is above, according to your requirement you can use,

**`params['message']['message_notification'] = (params['message']['message_notification'].to_json)`**

this converts the `message_notification` in the params to a `json object`, and stores in the DB.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly where `params['message']['message_notification'] = (params['message']['message_notification'].to_json)` goes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did.

```
  def resource_params
    params.require(:appointment_modules_dataset_intake).permit(
      :appointment_id,
      :main_issue,
      :cvf
    ).tap do |p|
      p[:cvf] = JSON.parse(p[:cvf]) # This is the significant line
    end
  end
```